# Triassic crocodile alternative

Tags: internal-consistency, creature-design, evolution, alternate-worlds

During the Triassic period there were many different varieties of crocodile related species. The dinosaurs weren't as prominent until after a poorly understood extinct event. If this event hadn't occured I'm guessing the crocodile would continue to thrive. But what would be the limits to their evolution? Is it too much to think they might evolve feathers? Or long necks for the herbivores? Is full on marine forms also wrong?

Comment: As evolution is impossible to predict in advance even with all known variables, instead perhaps tell us what you want to get to, and we can indicate how it might be possible to get there. It's more the sort of thing we can explain with known science.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are fossil records of what appear to have been a species of large long legged terrestrial crocodiles that would have filled a niche as apex predators in the area where they were found. If one species has been found its highly likely there were others.

There is also fossil evidence that early in their evolution and on into the age of dinosaurs crocodiles were well adapted to a wide variety of diets with the fossil remains of insectivorous species being found as well as those of omnivorous and vegetarian ones. So there's no problem at all with them theoretically spreading out to fill most ecological niches, at least in warmer climates. So yes, crocodilians could well have expanded out to fill other land based ecological niches in the absence of competition. Long necked crocs? Cant say.

As for salt water habits? The modern salt water crocodile is already well adapted to that environment so there's nothing I suppose to stop their ancient ancestors from becoming even better adapted if given the opportunity. For instance forgoing legs in favor of flippers like seals and whales did and developing similar deep diving abilities (at least in warm water environments).

Feathers and flying are probably a step to far however. Problem is they are poikilothermic and all birds and mammals are homeothermic. Its one of the defining features of reptiles and I'm not sure its not one they could realistically evolve out of except perhaps given an *extremely* long period of time. Same thing for feathers, they're one of if not the most important part of birds homeothermic adaptions.

Comment: Well, birds and mammals did evolve from poikilothermic reptiles.

Comment: Mammals split off from reptiles way before dinos appeared on the scene apparently. There were early (proto) mammals on the scene before the Triassic extinction event. Then later birds split off from dinosaurs. So mammals got fir, dinos got feathers and reptiles  (and crocs) stuck with scales.  It could have happened via another split off from reptiles if most existing members of other groups got wiped out I suppose. But there's no specific reason for it to have been crocs unless they were the ONLY reptiles left alive.

Comment: Birds are also homeothermic, if crocodiles are poikilothermic I would think the common ancestor of dinosaurs and crocs was like poikilothermic as well. And pterosaurs, who were also archosaurs like dinosaurs and crocs, were likely homeothermic since powered flight requires a lot of energy and at least some were covered in hair- or down- like integument.

Comment: @Hypnosifl crocodiles way well be secondarily poikilothermic, some anatomical and genetic features point towards an homeothermic ancestor. living crocodiles is bad group to jusge Suchia from, its like judging mammals based only on 2 seal species. also marine reptiles had already evolve long before the Triassic was over, they evolved right at the beginning of the Triassic.

Comment: @Hypnosifl. All true. Apart form that fact it didn't happen if dinos hadn't evolved post the Triassic to be the dominant land animal crocs could have done so - I suppose. But even allowing for the fact that the Jurassic & Cretaceous periods were a lot warmer than now they'd still have struggled to spread out into the colder polar regions of the Earth we know dinosaurs managed to colonize (at least on a migratory basis anyway). That is unless one branch of the family evolved some form of homeothermy.

Answer (score 0):

feathers are unlikely just because feathers are very unique structures. otherwise nearly anything is fair game. these early crocodilians (Pseudosuchia) are very close to the split between the line that leads to modern crocodiles and dinosaurs. speculative evolution on this scale is basically pointless the answer is almost always "**maybe"**

keep in mind T-rex is closer to us in time than it is to the end of the Triassic, there is a huge span of time there for diversification, competition, and other factors. Predictions are going to be very vague and speculative.

But they would likely be pretty close to what we have with the extinction plus some a variety of apex predators. keep in mind the the major groups of dinosaurs had already split off at this point, dinosaurs were already wide and diverse. the only thing the dinosaurs did not have was apex predators but the other niches were filled. so diversification would come from large predators and semiaquatic predators. the end of the Triassic extinction went so bad for the Suchia because they had become locked out of a the small body size niches except for a few semiaquatic crodillians. But the could have just as easily come up with wild paths we can't even imagine that is the problem with such vague questions about evolution, could they? Maybe.

marine reptiles had also already diversified before the Triassic extinction so that at least is out.

Without a specific question you will not get an better answer. I am going to vote to close your vague swath of questions but wanted to give a more detailed explanation than could fit in a comment.

Comment: You don't have to be so rude. I wanted to start a discussion, that means being vague is ok. Mon was able to say all you said in a much more constructive way

Comment: @JoeSmith discussions are off topic here please do not try to start another one.